# Application.Volatile for colored cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to use a function to count the number of times a red cell appears in a column. I retrieved the function from a previous SO answer.

```
Function CountRed(range_data As Range) As Long
Application.Volatile
Dim datax As Range
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        CountRed = CountRed + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

Now I inserted Application.Volatile to make it 'automatically update' anytime a new red cell appears. However, this doesn't seem to work. I think it's because changing a color doesn't really change the value of an actual cell.

How can I modify the function to account for changing red cells?

Comment: You can't. `Application.Volatile` will make the function recalculate whenever the workbook does but changing colours does not trigger a recalculation. Are the colours being changed manually or as the result of conditional formatting?

Comment: @Rory theyre being changed manually.

Comment: Can you use another method -  eg adding data to a cell and CF to colour as appropriate? It will make life a lot easier than trying to use colours as data.